# install-package : Dependency loop detected for package 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite'

Tags: powershell, nuget-package, packaging

I am trying to install `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` with PowerShell's cmdLet `install-package`:

```
$pkg = find-package -name Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
install-package -force -scope currentUser -verbose $pkg
```

The second command takes a long time and then responds with

```
install-package : Dependency loop detected for package 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package -force -scope currentUser -verbose $pkg
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : Deadlock detected: (Microsoft.Data.Sqlite:String) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DependencyLoopDetected,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Why is that and what do I have to do in order to install this package?

Comment: i recall seeing this for other packages - one of the posts linked to this >>> Installing System.Net.Http using Install-Package fails with "Dependency loop detected for package" · Issue #475 · OneGet/oneget — https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/475

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58417976/45375

Comment: @René Nyffenegger, -SkipDependencies works for me.

Answer (score 13):

First I Install the latest Nuget provider running following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
Install-PackageProvider Nuget –force –verbose
```

I resolved the trouble with another package where I met the same trouble using `-SkipDependencies` additional parameter :

```
Install-Package libphonenumber-csharp -Destination ".\NugetPackages" -Force -Source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2' -ProviderName NuGet -RequiredVersion '8.10.23' -SkipDependencies -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Then install-package works again for this package, I clearly don't understand why it suddendly stop working, but `-SkipDependencies` is for me the answer to dependency loop.

Comment: I'm not sure this will solve the problem.
This will only silence the errors.
Additionally the user may lose some functionalities by skipping dependencies

Comment: @AymenDaoudi for many packages it solves the error for me. For complex dependencies, you have to load each  package.  But if you prefered staid stuck.