# Unable to install MailKit .NET library in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, mailkit

According to [this article](https://adamtheautomator.com/how-to-send-email-securely-with-powershell/), one can install the MailKit library through Powershell using the code

`Install-Package -Name 'MailKit' -Source 'nuget.org`'

I've not been successful with the installation, which yields this error message:

```
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'MailKit'. Try
Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package -Name 'MailKit' -Source 'nuget.org'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

I have searched for a solution without success. When I tried adding the `Verbose` parameter, this is the output:

```
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'NuGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?id='MailKit'' for ''.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Install-Package MailKit -Version 2.9.0`as described [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) ? Mind you, it needs NuGet 2.12 or higher. You can download nuget from [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

Comment: Yes, I had already studied that document, but this code refers to the NuGet Package Manager, while I'm trying to access it via PowerShell. And I have NuGet v3.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install MailKit after following the recommendation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351619/install-package-dependency-loop-detected-for-package-microsoft-data-sqlite). I had to change the NuGet source from v3 to v2, for it to arrive at the point of returning the "Dependency loop" error. To install, I ran

```
Install-Package -Name "MailKit" -Source nuget.org -SkipDependencies
```

I consider this a quick and dirty fix, not a solution to the actual problem, as I had to also install the dependency **MimeKit** separately.

Comment: How did you install the dependencies to MimeKit separately?

Comment: Wow this was ages ago and I don't remember. Are you stuck with this?

Comment: it's okay, decided to do something else MailKit might be too advanced for me