# NuGet dependency loop detected installing Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I need to install the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild package. Is there anything I can do about this?

I used the command specified at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild, but it should specify `-RequiredVersion`.

```
PS C:\> Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild -RequiredVersion 16.0.62004.28040 -Scope CurrentUser -ProviderName 'NuGet' -Source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'

The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'nuget.org'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y
Install-Package: Dependency loop detected for package 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild'.
```

Comment: Sounds like the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59058025/9898643)